# Loading fixture with component test

Tags: cypress

Performing a Cypress component test, I load a fixture in a before hook.

The fixture loads, but disappears after the first test.

```js
before(() => {
  cy.fixture('my-fixture').as('fixture')
})

it('test1', function() {
  mount(component, {
    propsData: {'data': this.fixture},
  })
})

it('test2', function() {
  mount(component, {
    propsData: {'data': this.fixture},  // undefined
  })
})
```

How do I fix the fixture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alises are cleared down between tests. You can change the hook to `beforeEach()` to allow all tests to see the data.

Note that the fixture is not read from disk every time it's called, the `cy.fixture()` command has a cache the returns the previously read value on 2nd, 3rd calls.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.fixture('my-fixture').as('fixture')
})

it('test1', function() {
  mount(component, {
    propsData: {'data': this.fixture},
  })
})

it('test2', function() {
  mount(component, {
    propsData: {'data': this.fixture},  // passes
  })
})
```